# Problems with USB Stick

Tags: usb, mount, usb-drive, disk, format

I'm quite new using Ubuntu, I actually came from macOS. So I'm sorry not knowing basic stuff... But I've got experience using bash.
I'm using Ubuntu Dektop 18.04.

I failed using a "Spaceloop by CNMemory® Generic Flash Disk 8GB" USB Stick. I tried it also with macOS, but there where problems too.
Now, I tried to "repair" it under Ubuntu. I searched the whole internet and tried different stuff.

So first, I inserted the Stick into my USB Port. In "Files", I found nothing, neither in the sidebar, nor in "Other Locations". So I opened "Disks". I added a picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XORfR.png).

Unfortunately, I'm not abled to format the disk in the "Disks"-Utility. The option is grey...

Then, I changed to the Terminal and tried stuff with `mount, gdisk, fdisk, fsck, parted` and so on, but nothing was succesful. I will not post the whole bash session, that's too much :-)
But there was often the message, that the disk is "Read-Only-Filesystem". But how can I read it, and how can I mount it Read-Write?

But reading is not the most important thing, I think, there is nothing important on the Stick... I just want to use the Stick!

Please ask me if something is not clear, or if I should post some more information, e.g. some bash output or stuff like that :-)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Some USB drives have a read-write switch on the side which forces the electronics into read-only state until it's changed (most don't have this, but check), and the OS can't override this if correctly done.  When you `mount` it did you mount as rw? and if it mounted in read-only you are usually given error messages that is your clue as to why it was only mounted read-only (you can read-back these thru logs (`dmesg` `journalctl` ..) to remind yourself, but since gui tools hide many of these messages it may be necessary if using gui).

Comment: I actually do not know whether the stick is mounted. I cannot find anything in /mnt or /media. How exactly can I try it? `sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/username`?

Comment: Can you try to reformat to NTFS on macos ? ( I don't have a mac) On UBUNTU you can type lsblk to display mountpoints. But if it is not mounted it won't show, when I insert a usb drive with label "USB02" and type 'lsblk' it shows on last line.

Comment: To see if mounted; entering the command `mount` will show what is mounted.  I'd use `lsblk` (list block devices) to get info about device & if needed `lsblk |grep ..` to limit output. It's pretty much the same as macOS; GNU/linux is sysV rather than older sys4 of bsd/mac but differences are minor.  I'd suggest providing the specific commands like `mount` you'd like help with, and errors you got (ie. what you tried) & the output of commands like where you got sdb from so we can help you with where you got stuck. You mount to a directory; so your /media/username may shadow existing mounts!

Comment: What are you trying to use the stick for? Do you want to use it as a storage drive? Do you want to use it as an installer for Ubuntu? Do you already have Ubuntu installed?

Comment: I'm already using Ubuntu 18.04 and I just want to use the Stick as storage.

Comment: What I do not understand is that when I'm trying stuff with the stick, there is sometimes an error like "mounted Read-Only". But I think, it is not at all mounted, because I can not find the mountpoint. I'm just able to find the device file (/dev/sdb), but not the mounted file system (/mnt is empty, /media/username too). So the first step might be not writing to the stick, but finding the mount point to read the contents. But where can I find the stick's file system, when not in /mnt or /media? And how can I mount the stick?

Comment: OK no, the exact error is "/dev/sdb is a read-only file system". However, how can I mount it?

Comment: What I tried is to use `gdisk /dev/sdb`, there is the following output: `Partitioning table scan: MBR: not present; BSD: not present; APM: not present; GPT: damaged`. So I tried to create another table using `parted /dev/sdb` and then `mklabel msdos`, and when I type `print` after that, the partitioning table is showed as `msdos`, but when I restart `parted`, it is `GPT` again. So what can I do?